# x86 architecture specifications

Tags: x86, emulation, assembly

I want to write an IBM-PC compatible emualtor with C++ as an educational project, and in order to correctly emulate the 8086 processor need information on how it works.

Some examples for the information I would need:

- How is the code structured (size of single instructions, how are they unpacked, etc.)
- Exact workings of the registers
- Detailed information on what the single instructions do (For example the default description for the CMP command "Compares ... and ... and sets the flags" isn't enough for me)

I have already searched around for a few hours, but the information I got was more aimed at people trying to learn x86 assembly, and wasn't detailed enough

Maybe you can help me?

Answer (score 4):

You may want to go straight to the source:

http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/24319101.pdf

Answer (score 2):

[sandpile.org](http://sandpile.org) is a nice place if you need information about the encoding format of x86 opcodes. All the info is organized in tables for easy look-up.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the Intel architecture manuals:
http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/
(note: Otavio's link is better as it goes to an older manual)

Of course, these include specifications for a lot of instructions and features that didn't exist in the 8086, but you should be able to skip over the new stuff.

You may also want to look at [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) to check things or get some ideas.

Finally, unless you're already quite confident, I would recommend starting with a simpler (RISC) instruction set, such as one of the MIPS architectures. Instruction decoding and addressing modes are considerably less complex in a typical RISC architecture than they are in a typical CISC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The art of assembly language, by Randall Hyde. It has a couple of sections on how the processor works, for example:

**Chapter Three: System Organization**

- 3.0 Chapter Overview
- 3.1 The Basic System Components
- 3.1.1 The System Bus
- 3.1.1.1 The Data Bus
- 3.1.1.2 The Address Bus
- 3.1.1.3 The Control Bus
- 3.1.2 The Memory Subsystem
- 3.1.3 The I/O Subsystem
- 3.2 System Timing
- 3.2.1 The System Clock
- 3.2.2 Memory Access and the System Clock
- 3.2.3 Wait States
- 3.2.4 Cache Memory
- 3.3 The 886, 8286, 8486, and 8686 “Hypothetical” Processors
- 3.3.1 CPU Registers
- 3.3.2 The Arithmetic & Logical Unit
- 3.3.3 The Bus Interface Unit
- 3.3.4 The Control Unit and Instruction Sets
- 3.3.5 The x86 Instruction Set
- 3.3.6 Addressing Modes on the x86
- 3.3.7 Encoding x86 Instructions
- 3.3.8 Step-by-Step Instruction Execution
- 3.3.9 The Differences Between the x86 Processors
- 3.3.10 The 886 Processor
- 3.3.11 The 8286 Processor
- 3.3.12 The 8486 Processor
- 3.3.12.1 The 8486 Pipeline
- 3.3.12.2 Stalls in a Pipeline
- 3.3.12.3 Cache, the Prefetch Queue, and the 8486
- 3.3.12.4 Hazards on the 8486
- 3.3.13 The 8686 Processor
- 3.4 I/O (Input/Output)
- 3.5 Interrupts and Polled I/O